# python tkinter+threading/multiprocessing

Tags: python, многопоточность, tkinter, multiprocessing

Наверняка этот вопрос несколько вас смутит, так как скорее всего я ходил вокруг да около решения.

(принципиальной разницы в Python отсутствует, просто я пользуюсь Python 3.9)

Суть программы:

`Tkinter` окно предлагает выбрать из списка элемент для скачивания. После пользователь выбирает и начинается процесс скачивания и разархивации в Х-директорию. Это было организованно импортом из installer mn функцию (в прикрепленном коде видно).

Но нужно признать, что при вызове этой функции (на прямую, без `threading`) GUI Tkinter останавливается, так как происходит `requests.get` (в функции mn() модуля installer.

Сам вопрос:

1. `решено` - спасибо, Сергей Шашко!.
2. Как по нажатию `button1` запустить `threading.Thread(target=installer).start` (но я находил ответы в которых говорилось что лучше использовать `multiprocessing`).

Прилагаю код главного процесса:

```
import subprocess
import threading
from tkinter import *
#import os
#import asyncio
from installer import mn


res_packs = ['one','two']


def install(): #вызывается нажатием button1
    global ins_lbl
    try:
        mn(listbox1.selection_get()) #функия для начала скачивания

                try:
                    ins_lbl.destroy()

                except NameError:
                    pass

                ins_lbl = Label(root,text='Установка',fg='white',bg='black')
                ins_lbl.place(x=10,y=70)


            except TclError:
                try:
                    ins_lbl.destroy()
                except NameError:
                    pass

                ins_lbl = Label(root, text='Выбери!', fg='white', bg='red')
                ins_lbl.place(x=10, y=70)
        
        #GUI
        root = Tk()
        root.overrideredirect(True)
        root['bg'] = 'black'
        root.geometry('200x130+890+200')
        root.resizable(False,False)
        
        listbox1 = Listbox(root,height=5,width=15,selectmode=EXTENDED,selectbackground='#0d0d26',background='black',fg='red',selectforeground='red',activestyle='none')
        listbox1.place(x=100,y=5)
        for i in res_packs:
            listbox1.insert(END,i)
        
        thr = threading.Thread(target=install) #preinit
        not_suc_lbl = Label(root) #preinit
        suc_lbl = Label(root) #preinit
    
        button1 = Button(root,text='Установить',width=10,height=2,bg='#0d0d26',fg='red',bd=5,activebackground='#202042',activeforeground='white',command=thr.start) #кнопка что активирует install() функцию. --- проблема. если убрать threads и просто вызвать install, то GUI останавливается.
        button1.place(x=10,y=10)
    
        button2 = Button(root,text='Выход',width=5,height=1,bg='#0d0d26',fg='red',bd=5,activebackground='#202042',activeforeground='white',command=exit)
        button2.place(x=75,y=95)
    
        root.mainloop()
```

Так же код py файла, функция из которого вызывается при нажатии button1:

```
from os import system, remove
from sys import argv
from zipfile import ZipFile
from requests import get
from ctypes import windll


def mn(name):
    try:
        print('Start load')
        file = get(f'https://example.it/{name}.zip').content

        with open('file.zip','wb') as f:
            f.write(file)
        print('Success!')

        with ZipFile('file.zip','r') as f:
            print('Extracting')
            f.extractall()

        print('Success!')
        remove('file.zip')


    except Exception as error: #создания окна с ошибкой.
        answer = windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0,f"ERROR: {str(error)}","ERROR", 5)

        if answer == 4:
            system('cls')
            main()
        else:
            pass
```

Так же прилагаю фото самого окна, ежели вдруг нужно будет посмотреть графику (хотя я не думаю что это нужно..)

[image: window Tkinter GUI]

Comment: 1) Что за "взаимодействие" "главного и дочернего" процессов вы хотите установить? Например, дайте комментарий в тексте.
2) Какова цель "многократного запуска"? Сколько таких запусков нужно? 3) многопроцессность нужна при большой нагрузке на процессор, многопотчность - при большом количестве блокирующих операций ввода- вывода (это же ваш случай?). При неблокирующих - асинхронный режим рекомендуют. 4) Насколько принципиально, что python - 3.9? Зачем это в вопросе выделено?

Comment: 5) Что не так в коде сейчас?

Comment: A что мешает вам сделать  import installer?

Comment: Разделите на три основных модуля. Основа tkinter , функция сначивания и функция распаковки. В основе формуруем все задачи для скачивание этиже задачи с помочью многопоточности скачиваем, формуруем все задачи для распаковки с помочью многопоточности и распаковвываем. Надеюсь я понятно обьяснил.

Comment: Спасибо большое Сергей Шашко, я даже забыл об этом.

Сергей, я принял ваши замечания и подкорректировал вопрос. Надеюсь теперь понятнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чт.. ответ был очевиден... достаточно было просто создать ещё одну функцию, и вней создавать каждый раз новый поток... Вопрос решен, итоговый код:

```
import threading
from tkinter import *
import os
import requests
from zipfile import ZipFile
from ctypes import windll


res_packs = [1,2]


def mn(fl):
    threading.Thread(target=main,args=[fl]).start()


def main(name):
    try:
        print('Start load...')
        file = requests.get(f'https://{name}.zip').content
        with open('file.zip','wb') as f:
            f.write(file)
        print('Success!.')
        with ZipFile('file.zip','r') as f:
            print('Extracting...')
            f.extractall()
        print('Success!.')
        os.remove('file.zip')
    except Exception as error:
        answer = windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0,f"ERROR: {str(error)}","----------ERROR----------", 5)
        if answer == 4:
            os.system('cls')
            mn(name)
        else:
            pass

def install():
    global ins_lbl
    try:
        mn(listbox1.selection_get())
        try:
            ins_lbl.destroy()
        except NameError:
            pass
        ins_lbl = Label(root,text='Установка..',fg='white',bg='black')
        ins_lbl.place(x=10,y=70)
    except TclError:
        try:
            ins_lbl.destroy()
        except NameError:
            pass
        ins_lbl = Label(root, text='Выбери!', fg='white', bg='red')
        ins_lbl.place(x=10, y=70)


root = Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
root['bg'] = 'black'
root.geometry('200x130+890+200')
root.resizable(True,True)

listbox1 = Listbox(root,height=5,width=15,selectmode=SINGLE,selectbackground='#0d0d26',background='black',fg='red',selectforeground='red',activestyle='none')
listbox1.place(x=100,y=5)
for i in res_packs:
    listbox1.insert(END,i)


not_suc_lbl = Label(root)
suc_lbl = Label(root)
button1 = Button(root,text='Установить',width=10,height=2,bg='#0d0d26',fg='red',bd=5,activebackground='#202042',activeforeground='white',command=install)#thr.start)
button1.place(x=10,y=10)
button2 = Button(root,text='Выход',width=5,height=1,bg='#0d0d26',fg='red',bd=5,activebackground='#202042',activeforeground='white',command=exit)
button2.place(x=75,y=95)
root.mainloop()
```

Код вроде как работает, спасибо за помощь!